How to use python typing TypeVar as a Callable list of parameters?
Lets say I want a function that execute a function with its parameters (yes, this is useless, but also the simplest case I could think of) :
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, List, Any

Params = TypeVar("Params", bound=List[Any])    
    
def do_something(fn: Callable[Params , bool], params: Params)
    return fn(params)

def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

result = do_something(add, (1, 2))
print(result)

Right now, python typing is showing an error, as Params is neither a List or "...". Is there a way to use TypeVar so that my IDE understands that the function should take as arguments the same types as the ones passed as params ?

This question is similar to: Type hint generic function with arguments of passed function. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

ParamSpec is a general solution for such problems, but won't let you accept args as a single tuple - after all, what you're trying to wouldn't be safe for def fn(*, x: int) -> None. You could also try something like this for non-kwargs if you insist on using a tuple: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=7cc81b0e8631e46601d197d69e243223

@STerliakov THIS is the way, your link was exactly what I needed, this keeps the typing across a lambda passed as a fn parameter. Thanks !

You are trying to reinvent ParamSpec, a kind of type variable designed precisely for this purpose.
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec('P')
RV = TypeVar('RV')

def do_something(fn: Callable[P, RV], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs): -> RV
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)

def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

result = do_something(add, 1, 2)


While this seems to work, when I call the do_something function with a lambda as fn, the IDE does not seem to understand the type of the lambda's parameters from the passed named parameters :/

You can't provide type hints for a lambda expression, so the best anything could do is infer the type of such a function from the additional arguments. If your IDE doesn't try that, there's nothing else you can do.
